# mapping an array of strings to an array of numbers based on key value pairs of another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

I am trying to map an array of strings

```
arrString = [
      ["A", "B"],
      ["C", "D"],
      ["E", "F"],
      ["D", "A"],
      ["F", "C"],
      ["G", "E"]
    ]
```

based on an object of key values:

```
map =  {
  '0': 'A',
  '1': 'B',
  '2': 'C',
  '3': 'D',
  '4': 'E',
  '5': 'F',
  '6': 'G'
}
```

into an array of numbers

```
arrNum = [
      ["0", "1"],
      ["2", "3"],
      ["4", "5"],
      ["3", "0"],
      ["5", "2"],
      ["6", "4"]
    ]
```

This is what I have done:

```
    const map = {}
    const arrNum = Array.from(new Array(arrString.length), () => new Array(arrString[0].length).fill([]));
    for(let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
        map[i] = arr2[i]
    }
    for(let ele in arrString){
    // I can't figure out how to if the obbject value is equal to ele push it's key to arrNum
        if (Object.values(map).includes(ele)) 
    }
```

As you can see I am trying to loop through arrString and then if any element equals a value in map I want to add its key to arrNum.

So anyone knows how to do it so I can end up with `arrNum`?

Comment: Do you control the map? It would be better if the keys were the characters and the values were the numbers, not the other way around. Your map as it is is better suited as an array of characters

Comment: @NickParsons unfortunately I don't control the map

Comment: @Andy unfortunately I cannot control the map

Comment: Does the map change? Might `A` be assigned to `4` at some point for example? Or will each consecutive letter _always_ match a consecutive number starting from zero? @seyet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arrString = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "D"],
    ["E", "F"],
    ["D", "A"],
    ["F", "C"],
    ["G", "E"]
]

map = {
    '0': 'A',
    '1': 'B',
    '2': 'C',
    '3': 'D',
    '4': 'E',
    '5': 'F',
    '6': 'G'
}

const arrNum = arrString.map(as => as.map(a => {
    for(const k in map){
        if (map[k] === a) return k;
    }
}));

console.log(arrNum);
```

Comment: I just edited my post. The mapping should be done based on the map provided not alphabetic index

Comment: i corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
const arrString = [
    ["A", "B"],
    ["C", "D"],
    ["E", "F"],
    ["D", "A"],
    ["F", "C"],
    ["G", "E"]
];

map =  {
  '0': 'A',
  '1': 'B',
  '2': 'C',
  '3': 'D',
  '4': 'E',
  '5': 'F',
  '6': 'G'
};

const keys = Object.keys(map);
const arrNum = arrString.map(item => item.map(value => keys.find(key => map[key] === value)));

console.log(arrNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

First invert the map, then use it to match the letters.

```js
const arrString = [
      ["A", "B"],
      ["C", "D"],
      ["E", "F"],
      ["D", "A"],
      ["F", "C"],
      ["G", "E"]
    ] 
    
const map =  {
  '0': 'A',
  '1': 'B',
  '2': 'C',
  '3': 'D',
  '4': 'E',
  '5': 'F',
  '6': 'G'
}

const invertedMap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(map).map(([a,b])=>[b,a]))

console.log('Inverted Map:',invertedMap)

const output = arrString.map(inner => inner.map(char => invertedMap[char]))

console.log('Result:',output)
```